# Image doesn't show up on canvas

Tags: javascript, canvas

I'm experimenting with the `canvas` element, but for some reason it doesn't display my image.

I use the following code:

```
function Canvas() {
  this.field = function() {
    var battlefield = document.getElementById('battlefield');
    var canvas = battlefield.getElementsByTagName('canvas')[0];

    return canvas.getContext('2d');
  }
}

function Draw(canvas) {
  if (!canvas) {
    alert('There is no canvas available (yet)!');
    return false;
  }

  this.canvas = canvas;

  this.grass = function(pos_x, pos_y) {
    var terrain = new Terrain();
    var specs = terrain.grass();

    var img = new Image();
    img.onload = function(){
      canvas.drawImage(img, specs.position_x, specs.position_y, specs.dimension_x, specs.dimension_y, pos_x, pos_y, specs.dimension_x, specs.dimension_y);
      console.log('success???'); // this is being output
    };
    img.src = '/img/terrain.png';
  }
}

(function() {
  var canvas = new Canvas();
  var draw = new Draw(canvas.field());
  draw.grass();
})();
```

There are no errors, but the image just doesn't display. I've verified if the image exists and it does. I also verified the `specs` and they do contain what they should:

```
dimension_x: 25
dimension_y: 25
position_x: 0
position_y: 0
```

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

http://jsfiddle.net/uwkfD/3/

Comment: Is the `width` and `height` of the canvas set? Is the canvas element part of the DOM tree? Please create a http://jsfiddle.net/ demo.

Comment: @FelixKling using CSS: `width: 100%;`, `height: 300px;`.

Comment: CSS won't help, you have to set the `width` and `height` attributes/properties. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Canvas_tutorial/Basic_usage *Edit* I just read that the default size of a canvas is `300px x 150px`, so that should not be an issue.

Comment: maybe img/terrain.png instead of /img/terrain.png? not sure if that actually matters though

Comment: @FelixKling nopez still no luck when I set the attributes of the canvas element. `<canvas width="1000" height="300">
</canvas>`

Comment: @JoeTuskan nopez doesn't work.

Comment: Have a look at https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Canvas_tutorial/Using_images

Comment: @FelixKling that's the exact thing I'm using :)

Comment: Your code is still incomplete.  Are you passing `pos_x` and `pos_y` to `draw.grass`? I really suggest you to create a http://jsfiddle.net/ demo.

Comment: @FelixKling please see my demo: http://jsfiddle.net/uwkfD/

Comment: Looks like you aren't. Doing `.grass(0, 0)` works.

Comment: @FelixKling wtf you're right about the function params. But even when I do that it still doesn't show up :| ? Can you show me your update fiddle. Maybe it is a browser something. I'm on Chrome btw.

Comment: Please see my answer although there is nothing more than you already know. It worked for me in Chrome.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`pos_x` and `pos_y` are `undefined` in your code. It works if you pass values for them to `draw.grass()`:

```
draw.grass(0, 0);
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/uwkfD/4/)

Tested in Chrome and Firefox.

Comment: I still don't see it?!? http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/402/whereisit.png/ using your demo.

Comment: @MattGreer it isn't a matter of loading I'm sure of that. Lemme try another browser.

Comment: @PeeHaa: I had a `debugger` in the code, maybe this kept it from executing? It works fine for me: http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/828/1201020001.png/

Comment: @FelixKling thanks for all your help and pointing out the obvious! :P It's working now. Looks like Chrome canary was the culprit. Suits me right for devving in unstable browser. :(

Comment: Ah.. nice catch on the pos_x and pos_y.  I'm so used to working in languages where you can't call a function like that, or that my IDE alerts me to the error before I have to actually debug it!

Answer (score 2):

This may be because you need a context to draw on.

Try:

```
this.context = canvas.getContext('2d')
```

Then call your draw functions on the context object not the canvas object:

```
this.context.drawImage(img, specs.position_x, specs.position_y, specs.dimension_x, specs.dimension_y, pos_x, pos_y, specs.dimension_x, specs.dimension_y);
```

It also appears that your reference to `canvas` is wrong too, it should be `this.canvas` (or `this.context`) not just canvas, at least as I understand scope in javascript.

Comment: Good call with the context. But `canvas` will be available inside `this.draw` as this function is a closure.

Comment: You might be right about using `this.canvas`. Fixed that one. But still no luck. Regarding: `This may be because you need a context to draw on.`. That is in the this.canvas object. I have update my question to reflect this.

Comment: @MattG: PlexQ answered this question before the code was updated. Now this answer is obsolete.

Comment: @FelixKling: Yeah I realized that, so I deleted my comment.

Comment: Maybe I can learn something too, but I though that the canvas var was given in the scope of the object, and that this.grass was a member function, and the onload function, whilst a closure, would only pick up the context from the member function, not the object, and therefore you'd still have to use this.canvas (or this.context)?