# change logo in every div of my html page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have 5 div, each below the other in a main container div. Each div has a different height(say, first one has `height: 300px;`, second one has `height: 400px;` and so on). Each of these div also has an alternative background color of black/white.

I have a logo, one variant is white color and the other is black color which I want at a fixed position when page scrolls(white logo on a black div and black logo on white div).

In my code I placed a black logo at top left corner. Now my problem starts here. When I scroll the page, the black logo is not visible on black div, the same would happen when I have a white div and white logo.

I want that the black div show the white logo and white div show a black logo when the page is scrolled.  The position should be fixed.

This is my HTML:

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <img src="whiteLogo.png" style="position:fixed">
    <div class="first" style="background-color:#000"></div>
    <div class="second" style="background-color:#FFF"></div>
    <div class="thiree" style="background-color:#000"></div>
    <div class="four" style="background-color:#FFF"></div>
    <div class="five" style="background-color:#000"></div>
</div>
```

I created a JSfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ketan156/KqWQg/1/

Comment: please provide a js fiddle..

Comment: `document.querySelectorAll("div");`?

Comment: Can you show a fiddle?  Also,  what did you already try except changing the logo[from black to white and vice versa]?

Comment: where is logo in your div?

Comment: becuse black logo didn't show in back background and white didn't show in white if position fixed

Comment: show us a fiddle in www.jsfiddle.com

Comment: logo is on top=0 and left 10px; fixed position

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/ketan156/Bt7R3/

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/ketan156/KqWQg/1/

Comment: @PellePenna:  that is not a very elegant solution IMHO.

Comment: I agree .. I removed it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well try this using a simple CSS solution by keeping them fixed as you wanted.

**HTML:**

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="first black" style="height:300px;"></div>
  <div class="second white" style="height:400px;"></div>
  <div class="thiree black" style="height:500px;"></div>
  <div class="four white" style="height:300px;"></div>
  <div class="five black" style="height:200px;"></div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**[sorry for image size mismatch,  I guess you can handle that yourself.]

```
.black{
    background:#000 url(path/to/myWhiteLogo.png) no-repeat 10px 0px fixed;
}
.white{
    background:#FFF url(path/to/myBlackLogo.png) no-repeat 10px 0px fixed;
}
```

[JSFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/NLAvb/).

Note: I used some random DIV sizes as suggested by OP.  Also,  use small images instead of loading huge images and resizing them,  it will save bandwidth and load time.

Comment: thanks for answer it's correct. but i have canvas in one div background so on that div background-image not display.

Comment: How are you drawing the canvas?  Try looking at [this SO answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8696476/image-doesnt-show-up-on-canvas/8696591#8696591) for a start.

Comment: Glad you are on track. Cheers!!

Answer (score 1):

Could this be a way:

CSS

```
.black_logo {
    background: url(Black-Logo-PNG.jpg) no-repeat top left;
    background-size: 50px
}

.white_logo {
    background: url(White-Logo-PNG.jpg) no-repeat top left;
    background-size: 50px
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="first black_logo" style="background-color:#000; height:100px;"></div>
    <div class="second white_logo" style="background-color:#FFF; height:100px;"></div>
    <div class="thiree black_logo" style="background-color:#000; height:100px;"></div>
    <div class="four white_logo" style="background-color:#FFF; height:100px;"></div>
    <div class="five black_logo" style="background-color:#000; height:100px;"></div>
</div>
```

**Note:** And it's better to resize your logo to 50px instead of resize a big one using `background-size: 50px`

Comment: sorry, but it show all logo at same time. i need logo to be fixed. on top left of the screen. like this http://jsfiddle.net/ketan156/KqWQg/1/

Comment: This post might give you a way to start: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16444783/change-color-of-fixed-image-after-scrolling

Answer (score 0):

One solution, and it's not the ideal solution you are after but it will make the logo visible on both backgrounds is to add a solid white stroke onto the logo image, in photoshop for example. Or if you prefer, you could add a black stroke to the white version of the logo.

Comment: i try this but it look bad in my site.

Comment: Does it have to be black/white? What if you made the image greyish and semi-transparent? so that it looked more like a watermark.